# Typescript Generic Class Constraint

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have the example below which describes a structure to pass to the Jumpable class. When i pass the Test class i get an error.

```
type GConstructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

type Positionable = GConstructor<{ setPos: (x: number, y: number) => void }>;

function Jumpable<TBase extends Positionable>(Base: TBase) {
  return class Jumpable extends Base {
    jump() {
      this.setPos(0, 20);
    }
  };
}

class Test {
  constructor() {
    console.log();
  }

  setPos(x: number, y: number) {
    console.log();
  }
}

Jumpable<Test>(new Test());
```

> Type 'Test' does not satisfy the constraint 'Positionable'.   Type
> 'Test' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any[]): {
> setPos: (x: number, y: number) => void; }'.ts(2344)

Comment: [With this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gwgewHYGdgCcCuBjYD0A8AKgHxQC8USEA7lABQB0zAhugOYoBcULSIAbQC6ASgpkiAbgBQ00JCgAFBCgCWwVchYAjADbRK8ZGiy58BAN5QoAXxIzpAM0xJcmpFABSmALZgd+sQAQiwo0BAAHsAQSAAmKEoq6u4BECT0IWE8RJkQYhbS1ugQwJjoHti6oQnefqlQkdFxCblQBdbWAFa+YPT5hR3WA9Y2AzYyo9KV1VBEEGhtA9jGGDh46H2Lg8uoCPqMugjsfTIj0pO1-noQ9NR0c2h9IpJAA), I think I've proven it has to do with the constructor signature/type, not the method.

Comment: Well, `Jumpable()` wants a constructor, not an instance; like `Jumpable(Test)` instead of `Jumpable(new Test())`.  Is this just a typo or is there actual confusion about the difference between class constructors and class instances?

Comment: @jcalz i get the same error with just the Test

Comment: [No, it works fine](https://tsplay.dev/N9JDqm).  So this isn't just a typo?

Comment: The difference is between `Jumpable<Test>` and `Jumpable<typeof Test>` (the latter of which can be inferred by the argument that is passed in).

Comment: What is the difference between  Jumpable<Test> Jumpable<typeof Test>?

Comment: @nullromo What is the difference between Jumpable<Test> Jumpable<typeof Test>?

Comment: That I don't quite understand well enough to be able to confidently articulate. I was following this question to try and learn more.

Comment: @jcalz Can you enlighten us about  the difference between Jumpable<Test> Jumpable<typeof Test>?

Comment: Yeah, I'm writing up an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to understand the difference between JavaScript **values** which exist at runtime, and TypeScript **types** which exist only at compile time.

A type is kind of like a set of possible values. In the following code:

```
let x = "hello";
```

the variable `x` will hold the *value* `"hello"` at runtime, while the TypeScript compiler infers that it has the *type* `string`.  And `"hello"` is one of the possible values that make up the `string` type, so that's fine.  In the above, we could say "the type of `x` is `string`".

If you have a variable like `x`, you can ask TypeScript what its type is, by using [the TypeScript `typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) in a type context (not to be confused with [the JavaScript `typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)):

```
type TypeofX = typeof x;
// type TypeofX = string
```

---

Values are not types and types are not values.  Much of the time there is a clear and obvious difference between values and types in TypeScript, or the difference is minor enough to ignore.  For example, "singleton" or "unit" types that correspond to exactly one value are often given the same name as the value, like the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"hello"` corresponds to the value `"hello"`, so you could get by just fine conflating one with the other.

**But sometimes a value and a type can share a name but the value and type do not correspond directly to each other.**  The major situation where this happens is with `class` declarations.

In the following:

```
class Foo {
    x: string = "hello"
}
```

we have declared a `class` named `Foo`. At runtime, in JavaScript, this will create a *value* named `Foo` which is a class constructor.  The value named `Foo` can be invoked as a constructor like `new Foo()`.  TypeScript also knows about this value.

Additionally, the `class` declaration also brings into scope a TypeScirpt *type* named `Foo`, which corresponds to *instances* of the class.  A value of type `Foo` should have an `x` property of type `string`.

And **the type of the `Foo` value is not the `Foo` type**.  They are different.  The type of the `Foo` value, `typeof Foo`, has a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) like `new () => Foo`.  But the type named `Foo` has no such construct signature.

Observe:

```
const foo: Foo = new Foo();
const fooAlias: { x: string } = foo;

const fooCtor: typeof Foo = Foo;
const fooCtorAlias: new () => Foo = fooCtor;

const nope: Foo = Foo; // error! 
// Property 'x' is missing in type 'typeof Foo' but required in type 'Foo'
const alsoNope: typeof Foo = new Foo(); // error!
// Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'Foo' but required in type 'typeof Foo'
```

The `foo` and `fooAlias` variables are of type `Foo` or an equivalent type and hold an instance of the `Foo` class.  The `fooCtor` and `fooCtorAlias` variables are of type `typeof Foo` or an equivalent type and hold the `Foo` class constructor.  If you try to assign one to the other, you get errors.

---

So, let's look at your code:

```
type GConstructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

type Positionable = GConstructor<{ setPos: (x: number, y: number) => void }>;

function Jumpable<TBase extends Positionable>(Base: TBase) {
  return class Jumpable extends Base {
    jump() {
      this.setPos(0, 20);
    }
  };
}
```

Here, the `Jumpable()` function wants a `Base` parameter of type `TBase` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Positionable`, a type with a construct signature that constructs instances of type `{ setPos(x: number, y: number) => void }`.  A `Positionable` must be a class constructor.  This all makes sense because `Jumpable()` returns a new class constructor that is a subclass of the passed-in `Base`.  It looks like a [mixin class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#support-for-mix-in-classes) factory.

**`Jumpable()` wants its input to be a class constructor.**

When you call this, though:

```
Jumpable<Test>(new Test());
```

You have passed it a value of type `Test`.  `Jumpable()` doesn't want a value whose type is `Test`; that's a class *instance*, not a class *constructor*.  You get the error:

```
Jumpable<Test>(new Test()); // error!
// Type 'Test' does not satisfy the constraint 'Positionable'.
// Type 'Test' provides no match for the signature 
// 'new (...args: any[]): { setPos: (x: number, y: number) => void; }'
```

which tells you exactly the problem: you are trying to use the instance type `Test` in a place that needs a constructor type.  `Test` is not a constructor; it has no construct signature; it's wrong.  If you compile and run that code, you'll get a runtime error too, like

```
//  Base is not a constructor
```

---

The right thing to do is to give `Jumpable()` what it wants: a class constructor.  Presumably you want to make a subclass of `Test`, so you should pass in the `Test` constructor directly:

```
Jumpable<typeof Test>(Test) // okay
```

The type `typeof Test` is assignable to `new () => Test`, which is assignable to `new (...args: any[]) => Test`, which is assignable to `new (...args: any[]) => { setPos: (x: number, y: number) => void; }`, so the compiler is happy.  Even better, this code will work at runtime.

Note that you don't have to specify type parameters if the compiler can infer it, so this has the same effect as just

```
Jumpable(Test); // also okay
```

which is more idiomatic.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAHhC8ECIAWJjAPYINwCgD0eEokUAXBAM5gBOAlgHYDmOOYAngA4gQAqnI6AGYANOBHZch0XAXH9e-IaPhU6TFjgDGwAIYUKEAGLp0EAN44IV6OVUNGY5KgwIcAX3yFteg8fQtNdHoqCEETcj8xehAAdyMTAAoASlxA4Mgw9ABBYFo9cjMbShp7CDcxTNwtIJDMgGEwdGpyCQFBeNN4P1SajJMGppy8inJouOS4AD4Oiv7G6iq0kPp0LgiTMW6IWRBqaiaAQghPCAAFfa5qdggAcigbiFoDAFsnilKGOS5b1qk-B4ARgBXSDUEAARyBtDBABNHvQvtwbv9qukIDpgBR0AA5VYgFqKdqReBjDrJLDbQi7fbUA4nc54q5sW4cfaNVoPJ4QV76D4I1q3f4QYGgiFQ2HwxE-QkdG4sAUAcTqvWoQM08wAPDxpiTYhAEgA6I06aiMEbo+hsADaAF0klNeFUBad0O8wLQgjoAaAxEqVWrNYUKOAXeaEmQIPQgc8AbsADQQNijaOx6j22DTABu6FocLckyqgiB9HVHoRACloxwvaAtQAhPTcEBQMAgegwgyh2juz3ekCTBIN4PkHhDkD2izWCBgsBA6gI7z6CCV57VvsQZut9sGMfmSxT6wAKyrE0nB-PYCQTwNwbAoYSAAYEwAmB8pffnjxTty4DxaXRLjwIAhGeVhLDQAZNKeH4Hks6CgAaGCMOSMF-lOt73hGUYxvGibJjhaZ7ueYE1PBICIegyHvt+7gsCua61kBVADqSTFgMkKSUhueyHCcfDfDcbEPDC6DAZG6CQBQOjuhQgjMpe3DgdQOgMJANxdj29A1iANwGic0nTsW7rPNwu5ciskA6BASmQdQxw4PR2kJKxwHsUknE7DxtJ8fIgmuQ8rLoJmuZiSs3LSZoSChE04goJQtCMFps5gscsg3KShrGqa5o6JatpJAUlAhq65DhvhqYJkmkYprs6ZZjmMIUm4ukJM+ADMAAsACsSR0VWTlsR5hAagAtCN4ncTSDn9X2Gq-O0bEDoNXGjeNGJYhN1JNAmIoTWCehBOIpgxHQraxU8QA)

Comment: jcalz coming through with another clear and thorough answer. I never fully understood that declaring a class creates both a value at runtime and a typescript type like this. "The type of the Foo value is not the Foo type" is huge. And now I get the difference between class constructors and class types.